# Присваивание переменной результата функции

Tags: python

Python работает следующим образом:

[image]

В пятой строке у нас в переменную `a` записывается результат работы функции и потом, несмотря на то, что я изменил значения `x`, при вызове `a` в девятой строке по-прежнему остается `2`. Т.е. при вызове `a` значение не пересчитывается, а берется из памяти.

Вопрос: как добиться пересчета значения при каждом вызове переменной `a`, чтобы увидеть в 10-й строке `3`?

Comment: Печаль какая... Вы думаете при изменении x каждый раз вызывается функция и присваивается переменной?

Comment: Вызывается только первый раз, а мне нужно сделать, чтобы каждый.

Comment: @breaf Так можно только на классах, юзая декоратор `@property`. Тогда метод класса выглядит как его свойство и вызывается каждый раз при запросе этого псевдосвойства

Comment: попробовал со свойством, в моем случае не помогло ибо, как выяснилось ниже, choices рассчитан только на статику. Зато во вьюшке работает как я хотел.

Comment: См. комментарии к ответу @eigenein. Не нужно выяснять ничего, у django хорошая документация :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выполнить пересчет явно:

```
a = f()
```

Переменные хранят значения до тех пор, пока им не присвоено другое значение.

Comment: ну это разумеется, только вот ситуация реальная на django-проекте и явно еще раз вызвать не получится.

вот одно поле из класса формы:
address_city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'span12',}, choices=get_region_tree()))

функция get_region_tree делает запрос к базе и возвращает нужный список, но беда в том, что в базе может добавиться записей, а на форме в выпадающем списке все по-прежнему. И так до перезагрузки сервера. Не могу добиться того, чтоб choices пересчитывались каждый раз, а не брались из памяти

Comment: @breaf, прочитайте внимательно в документации раздел про [Relationship fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related).

Comment: Не может быть. Покажите функцию `get_region_tree`

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, прочитал еще раз,  у меня в моделе ForeignKey, все довольно просто, но в качестве choices нужен древовидный список, где страны как заголовки групп, а города можно выделить.

Функция готовит список под choices:
<pre>
def get_region_tree():
    countries = Region.objects.filter(region_type="country")
    output = []
    for country in countries:
        list = []
        for cities in country.get_all_cities():
            for city in cities:
                list.append((city.id, city.name))
        output.append((country.name, list))
    return output
</pre>

Comment: [...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related)But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you're probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much, if ever.

Не оформляю это как ответ, ибо вопрос изначальный совсем не про django. В следующий раз задавайте вопрос по конкретной проблеме, а не по (невозможности) ее решения одним из придуманных вами вариантов. Тогда границы - шире, вероятность решения - больше

Comment: @qnub, а почему не может такого быть? `wsgi` же. Функция вызвалась единожды, когда вызывался конструктор `CharField` и... вуаля!

@breaf, вредный совет. Хотите, чтобы работало **именно так**, модифицируйте окружение, чтобы не юзать `wsgi` :D

Comment: Я пытался решить проблему сам, разобрав ее на составляющие, вопрос мой был по python, а на джанго тема перешла уже по ходу обсуждения. В общем, верный ответ дал @eigenein, пока пересчет явно не сделаешь значение переменной будет прежним - его и принимаю.
В форме поле select решили заменить на текстовое с автокомплитом. Вопрос закрываю. Всем, кто уделил внимание спасибо.

Comment: я еще с 0.96 джанги диначиские чойсы забиваю при инициализации формы, как в ответе на данный вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field . Наверное за это время придумали какой-то более хороший способ.

Answer (score 4):

А теперь немного особенной, питонячьей магии:

```
from random import random

class Foo(object):

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return random()

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value)
        pass  # just ignore...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return random()

foo = Foo()
print foo.bar  # random!
foo.bar = 1
print foo.bar  # random again!

print foo.baz  # wow... random!
print foo.wtf  # wtf?! random again!
```

Comment: <offtopic>Не пытайтесь повторить этот эксперимент дома самостоятельно!</offtopic>